# How should I use takeUntil with an Observable that returns an Observable?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I am attempting to create an observable for watching websocket events.

The first observable calls onNext for each connection event and passes the websocket instance that connected as the next value.

Then another observable needs to be created that listens to disconnect events from that sockets. When such an event happens then the first observable needs to be completed. I am thinking something along the lines of flattening or merging however am unsure as to the correct approach to use.

```
// create an observable for each new socket connection event to server
const getSocketObservable = (socketServer) =>
  Observable.fromEvent(socketServer, 'connection')
    .takeUntil(
        socket => Observable.fromEvent(socket, 'disconnect')
    )
```

Here are both my test cases

```
describe('getSocketObservable', () => {
  let wss = null
  let mockSocket = null

  beforeEach(() => {
    wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 3000 });
    mockSocket = new EventEmitter()
  })

  afterEach((done) => {
    wss.close(done)
  })

  it('returns observable on new server connection event', () => {
    const onNext = spy()
    getSocketObservable(wss).subscribe(
      value => onNext(value),
    )
    wss.emit('connection', mockSocket)
    expect(onNext.calledWith(mockSocket)).toBe(true)
  })

  it('returned observer source should complete when socket disconnects', () => {
    const onCompleted = spy()
    getSocketObservable(wss).subscribe(
      value => console.log(value),
      err => console.log(err),
      onCompleted
    )
    wss.emit('connection', mockSocket)
    mockSocket.emit('disconnect')
    expect(onCompleted.calledOnce).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

The following naive approach  using take(1) makes the test cases pass. However I need the completion of the resulting observable to happen only on a disconnection event not after the first arbitrary value.

```
    export const getSocketObservable = (socketServer) =>
  Observable.fromEvent(socketServer, 'connection').take(1)
```

How can I make the above tests pass?

Comment: Why do you need the Observable to stay alive until disconnection? If it is meant to listen to connection and to forward the socket instance, what more use could it have? the connection event is a single event stream, no?

Comment: The Observable is watching the socket server for a connection event. This event is triggered whenever a new socket connects. Multiple sockets can connect at the same time. Therefore this observable is a stream of multiple connect events. However I don't think the the observable should complete until the server closes.

Comment: In your first code block, you call `.fromEvent(socket, 'disconnect')`. Does this mean the disconnection of that socket instance (meaning other sockets are still open)? Your last comment gave me the impression that you wanted to listen for the socket server itself to close.

Comment: Correct a given socket instance emits that event.

Comment: If I understand right, each socketServer connection produces a new socket instance right? So once a single socket instance disconnects, you want to stop listening to socketServer connection events entirely? Even if there are other open socket instances?